# Evaluate $\int\frac{dx}{x(2-\ln x^2)}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How to evaluate $\displaystyle\int\frac{dx}{x(2-\ln x^2)}$?

I tried to use an operator, but before that I distributed so $\displaystyle\int\frac{dx}{(2x-x\ln x^2)}$ my operator was $-x\ln x^2$ am I supposed to change its sign? However, after doing this I got $\displaystyle\int\frac{-x\ln x^2}{(-2x^2\ln x^2+1)}$ then my $u$ became $(-2x^2\ln x^2+1)$ so I have a problem to integrate it here. I also did the product rule for differentiating. Am I wrong for using an operator? I'm doing advance lessons, I hope someone can help.

Comment: Is it $ln(x^2)$ or $(lnx)^2$?

Comment: @Minethlos lnx^2 so I think its $ln(x^2)$

Comment: Try to keep things simple - let $u = 2 - \ln (x^2)$. What is the $du$?

Comment: @izœc um, $\frac{-2}{x}$?

Comment: Pretty much! Just don't forget $dx$, so that $du = \frac{-2}{x} dx$. So, then you know that $- \frac{1}{2} du = \frac{1}{x} dx$, so you could rewrite the integrand as $$ \int \frac{1}{u} \cdot \frac{-1}{2} du = \frac{-1}{2} \cdot \int \frac{1}{u} du.$$ That's probably an integral that looks familiar.

Comment: @izœc so it's -$\frac{1}{2}$$ln(2-lnx^2)+C$ ?

Comment: Almost... remember, unless we have special cases about the domain we are integrating on, or the function in the $\ln$, in general we have $\int \frac{1}{u} du = \ln |u| + C$. So, here it should be $$ \frac{-1}{2} \ln |2 - \ln (x^2)| + C .$$ You can rewrite this as $ \ln \left( \frac{1}{ \sqrt{ |2 - \ln (x^2)| } } \right) + C $.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint :**

Use substitution $u=\ln x$, you will get
$$\int\frac{dx}{x(2-\ln^2x)}=\int\frac{du}{2-u^2}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\int\frac{du}{\sqrt{2}-u}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\int\frac{du}{\sqrt{2}+u}$$

**Edit :**

Assuming the problem is
$$\int\frac{dx}{x(2-\ln x^2)}$$
then making substitution $u=\ln x$ we have
$$\int\frac{dx}{x(2-\ln x^2)}=\int\frac{dx}{x(2-2\ln x)}=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{du}{1-u}$$
The latter expression is trivial.

Comment: okay.. So that's gonna be, du= $\frac{dx}{x}$ so I'll have $\frac{du}{2-u^2}$?

Comment: @Mickey Yes. I added some details. The last expression is using partial fractions

Comment: Well, the question has $lnx^2$, but you have $ln^2 x$...

Comment: I think that this is solving a different (but still interesting) problem - it is due to the confusion over the meaning of $\ln x^2$. It is unclear if this is signifying $( \ln x)^2$ or $\ln (x^2)$, both of which are unambiguous.

Comment: @Minethlos I'm confused now after seeing the $\ln x^2$.

Comment: @Mickey Can you clarify this notation $\ln x^2$? Is it $(\ln x)^2$?

Comment: @venus $lnx^2$ I think I got the answer -$\frac{1}{2}$$ln(2-lnx^2)+C$? if I use $U=(2-lnx^2)$?

Comment: @Mickey I edited my answer.

Comment: That's a nice way of doing it also.

Answer (score 1):

u=2-log x^2

```
du=-2dx/x
```

answer will be -(log|2-log x^2|)/2

Comment: Learn LaTeX from here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/146687